# Encrypt in SQL server and read/decrpyt client-side

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, encryption

Ive written in sql :

```
CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY SecureSymmetricKey
    WITH ALGORITHM = TRIPLE_DES
    ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'StrongPassword';
```

---

```
DECLARE  @str NVARCHAR(1000)
SET @str = 'lala';

OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SecureSymmetricKey
    DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'StrongPassword';
```

---

```
DECLARE @encrypted_str VARBINARY(MAX)
SET @encrypted_str = 
          EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('SecureSymmetricKey'), @str);
```

- the encrypted_str value is in a table now.

**how can i read it in c# ? ( and decrypt in c# )**

Comment: please show some source code... what have you tried ? what is not working ?

Comment: @Yahia , everything is working but now when i have it  encrypted in the sql , and sending the encrypted data to the c# , How do i DECRYPT the data in the C# ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir What are you actually doing, give more details in your original post of what you are trying to do as a big picture, and what you are trying to protect your self from by adding encryption (the term is "Threat Model"). We can give a better solution then.

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain , thanks a lot for fixing my head , so can you please answer my other question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838548/symmetric-key-certificates-role-in-sql-server     ? thank you

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain , you deleted you post which helped me alot to understand. Im trying ( and i think im in the wrong irection) to read the `byte[] ` of the  encrypted data and in c# to decrypt the byte[] to the original data. - but i think im in the wrong way.

Comment: @Yahia Can you please answer my question in : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838548/sqlserver-symetric-key-certificates-games-by-hacker ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't "decrypt" it in C#.  Decrypt it in the select statement on the way back out.

Comment: So i think my misunderstood the topic... If i want to save the data  + encryption , Do I encrypt it in the `c# before sending` or in the `insert command` (sql)

Comment: can you please answer my question at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838548/symmetric-key-certificates-role-in-sql-server ? Im dealing with it all day :(

Answer (score 2):

You need to encrypt and decrypt at the same layer of your application stack; if you encrypt at the SQL Server layer, you need to decrypt before returning the data to your application.

If you want to decrypt it in the C# application, you need to encrypt it there first, and store the encrypted values in the database.

Comment: can you please answer my qustion at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838548/symmetric-key-certificates-role-in-sql-server ?

Comment: , what about creating a certificate ? its not envolved with password so any hacker which has the bak file  -can see the data...?